# Why are some files not loaded in my Google Search Console account (URL Inspection)?

Tags: seo, google-search-console

My website works well, but Google Search Console shows me that even style.css files can't be loaded, and many more files are not loaded as well.
Please let me know why it is? And how to fix it?

Image of the errors (Look at "other errors" on the right side):

[image: Errors on the right side]

Answer (score 2):

You didnt make it easy.  I typed the url in.  According to [validator.w3.org](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https://www.designeling.com/static/style.css) there are errors in the **css**.  I havent tried the other links, its too much to type in.

You also have 21 errors in your html on the main page.

I would suggest that you use some online website checking tools.  There are some free ones around.

I have [HTMl Validator extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/html-validator/bocbjjpebcmehmadhaiefilfieahhcmo) on my Chrome browser.  I think that something like that is a must.  Because you want your **html** and **css** clean to get the best results out of **GSE**.  I am not associated with it.

[image: Result of css check]

Comment: Wow, thank you for the tip! I didn't know that I have some errors. Is that the cause of not loading .css to a google bot? It doesn't load it at all. :(

Comment: Some errors will definitely cause it to ignore the css.  Its hard to know which ones.  I just ensure that my css and html are perfect.  As per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, accept it and even upvote it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: Thank you so much for your consultation. I've upvoted your answer but not accepted it yet because I am not sure that it is the cause, because I see it also ignores even some images, probably the problem is not only the errors in the css and html. Anyway - I've fixed it - thank you so much, maybe it will help. Many thanks again.

Answer (score -2):

There could be several reasons why some of your website's pages or files are not loaded in your Google Search Console account's URL Inspection tool. Here are a few possible reasons:

1. The page hasn't been crawled yet: Google crawls websites periodically to index their content. If a new page or file has been recently added to your website, it may take some time before Google crawls and indexes it. You can check the "Coverage" report in Search Console to see if Google has crawled the page yet.
2. The page is blocked by robots.txt: If you have a robots.txt file on your website that blocks Google from crawling certain pages or directories, those pages won't show up in the URL Inspection tool. Check your robots.txt file to ensure that it's not inadvertently blocking the pages you're trying to inspect.
3. The page has a "noindex" tag: If the page has a "noindex" meta tag in its HTML code, Google won't index it and it won't show up in the URL Inspection tool. Check the source code of the page to ensure that it doesn't have a "noindex" tag.
4. The page has a "nofollow" link: If there is a "nofollow" link pointing to the page, Google may not index it. Check the links pointing to the page to ensure that they don't have a "nofollow" attribute.
5. The page is duplicate content: If the page has identical or nearly identical content to another page on your website or another website, Google may not index it. Check the page for duplicate content and consider adding unique content to it.

If none of these reasons apply to your situation, there may be other issues that require further investigation. In that case, it may be helpful to consult with an SEO specialist or submit a support ticket to Google.

Comment: The question isn't asking about pages, it is asking about page resources such as JS, CSS, and images. None of your bullet points are at all relevant to the question.